# Failing to create a folder in flutter

Tags: flutter

i hve set this permission in manifest file

```
  android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="35" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and in <Application i have added this line

```
 android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

I have read some question and answers here...but still failing to create a folder..

i have taken two String for path,
it works with path1 but i want to create directory as path 2

```
 onPressed: ()async{
                String folderName = "logic";
String path1 = '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.noteapp/$folderName';

String path2 = '/storage/emulated/0/$folderName';


                await Directory(path2).create();
            }
```

I am trying in my physical device that has android 13